# advice to turn non responsive input field into responsive field

Tags: html, css

I found this example somewhere and found I to beautiful to not use it. Disadvantage of copy en pasting code is most of the time it isn't responsive in the way you want it. My question is are there a few basic rules or "keys" to make it easier to change non responsive into responsive? I'm always struggling with this because in this example you can't just change the height to 100% instead of 40px but you also need to calculate the custom changes with pixels. Thanks in advance!

```css
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Input ]*/

a:link {color: grey; text-decoration: none;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: grey; text-decoration: none;}   /* visited link */
a:hover {color: grey; text-decoration: none;}     /* mouse over link */
a:active {color: grey; text-decoration: none;}    /* selected link */

input  {   
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.wrap-input100 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  margin: 2%;

}

.input100 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align:left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/ 
.focus-input100 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focus-input100::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;

  background: #6a7dfe;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #21d4fd, #b721ff);
}

.focus-input100::after {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 1.2;

  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100::after {
  top: -15px;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input100 + .focus-input100::after {
  top: -15px;
}

.has-val.input100 + .focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}




.innerMargin {
    padding: 10% 0% 10% 0%;
  width: 100%;
    background-color: #21d4fd;  
    border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <input class="input100" type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control">
  <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="password"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `col-sm-12` in your div's class but you need bootstrap for it to works. See the example here [Bootstrap 4 Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input col-sm-12">
  <input class="input100" type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control">
  <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="password"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can I use a grid to?